# Print a number from 0 to inputted number that divisible by 3 or end with 3

Tags: java, math

There's one hidden test case that this code doesn't work and I don't know why. [EDITED] Sorry for the lack of information. I'm using an app to learn Java and this is a coding test, there are 4 total test with 4 different inputs, the first 3 one is fine but the last one (hidden so I don't know the input and output) told me that it's wrong but I don't know what's wrong in my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
       int number = read.nextInt();
       int x = 3;

       while(number > 3 && x <= number)
       {
           if(x%3==0 || x%10==3)
           {
               System.out.println(x);
           }
           ++x;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What does "hidden test case" mean? What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

If number = 3, your while loop does not run, and since 3 is divisible by 3 it should be printed.

You can just remove that part from your while loop, and leave this.

```
while(x <= number)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you just ignoring when the number is 3. Your condition number > 3 is ignoring when the number == 3.

DO like this `while(number >= 3 && x <= number)` instead of `while(number > 3 && x <= number)`

```
while(number >= 3 && x <= number)
   {
       if(x%3==0 || x%10==3)
       {
           System.out.println(x);
       }
       ++x;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing is x>3 condition is wrong as x==3 is also true.
Other thing is, why would you use an extra condition and increase complexity when you can just do a simple for loop/ while loop from 0-number and check if number %3 or number%10 is true?